# SwiftUI Text field gap

Tags: ios, swiftui

Please, help me:
Did you know, how to delete a free space between a Title and List Item?

[image]

I trying find solution myself, but I dont know, how this gap a called..
Please, help me find solution

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like an offset of -140. Maybe you should add an expected result so you can get an advice on how to get to it. Also pasting your code here would be nice so people can copy it and play around with it.

Comment: Please see [ask] including the part about including code as text, not an image, and including a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in your screenshot, you have applied padding to the top of the `VStack` containing the `Text` titles, but then compensated for this padding by applying a negative y-offset to the surrounding `ZStack`. You have also set a fixed height of 300 on the `ZStack`.

When you apply an offset to a view, it does not change the way that the view consumes space in the layout. So the gap is probably being caused by the `ZStack` in its natural position.

I would suggest you remove the padding, the fixed frame height and the negative y-offset. You might find that this eliminates the gap, but in any case it will give you a better starting point for sorting out the layout and padding.